# Importing object is undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm trying to split up my credentials for my Twitch bot so I can put it in my .gitignore so it won't be uploaded to GitHub. I'm exporting this:

credentials/twitchCredentials.js

```
let identity: {
    username: 'instakbot',
    password: 'testerino'
};

export default identity;
```

I try to import it in components/Chat/ChatContainer

```
import identity from 'credentials/twitchCredentials';
console.log(identity);
```

but this returns an undefined in the console... When I try to import the Chat component it's totally working

```
import {ChatMessage} from 'components/Chat';
```

components/ is on the same level as credentials/, so it shouldn't result in any problems... I'm using webpack 1.13.2.

Comment: `let identity: {` is a syntax error, it should be `let identity = {` (and even better, be `const`)

Comment: Oh lord. It's always the stupidest things that are wrong... Thanks for pointing that out. (I know about the const, it used to be that, but I also even tried var, just for the sake of trying every possible little thing...) Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I *do* wonder though why this didn't throw a syntax error.

Comment: Indeed... If I were able to troubleshoot that I would've been able to find it myself...

Comment: You're likely using `babel-preset-react` which means you have https://flowtype.org/ parsing enabled, and what you have here is a flowtype annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergi commented:

> let identity: { is a syntax error, it should be let identity = { (and
>   even better, be const)